# ¿Cómo cambiar el color de un checkbox?

Tags: java, css3, primefaces

Buenas tardes,

necesito cambiar el color de un checkbox en estado inactivo que se encuentra 
en una columna, con un `theme` de `primefaces` pero no se como hacerlo.

Codigo:

```
<p:column  id="SelectFuentes"  style="width:16%;text-align:center;  " selectionMode="multiple"  exportable="true">
```

Imagen:

El checkbox se encuentra en la ultima columna, cuando no hay datos en la tabla no se distingue el checkbox por el color del encabezado, pero cuando la tabla contiene datos el checkbox logra distinguirse.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito hacer que el checkbox se distinga del encabezado, pero no logro hacerlo ya que no se modifica, solo se modifica el `background` pero no se modifica el check.

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Ya intentaste agregar la propiedad  border en el style (style="border: #2929FF")

Comment: @SoftMolina si ya lo acabo de intentar, pero sige igual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para modificar una clase css de prime faces puedes optar por sobre escribir dicha clase  apoyandote de CSS, a lo que entiendo es que quieres cambiar un color a incactivo, espero este ejemplo cumpla con lo que busques:

- .ui-chkbox Main container element.
- .ui-chkbox-box Container of checkbox icon.
- .ui-chkbox-icon Checkbox icon.
- .ui-chkbox-label Checkbox label.

```css
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
    border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
    background: #d6d6d6;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #555;
}
```